# Measure ASP.NET method performance client-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I have a web application in ASP.NET with a save function at one point, that I want to measure the execution time since our users are complaining about the save process being slow.

I get the idea that I could add a client-side script on the button to get the starting time of the method call, but is there a way, still on the client side, to know when the save process is complete, to know the end time? Or should I consider the end time at the end of the method execution, since it is done on server-side?

Basically, I need to know the time it takes when the user hits the save button until they are returned to the other page after the save.

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Comment: As stated below, your .NET code is always run server side, so if that's where you think your bottleneck is, you can do a test to see how long the function is taking.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? Im having the same issue and want to check this from the client site. I saw a sample in java, it saves the start time and end time to a cookie and do something after that. I didn't read the whole thing as it had about 7-8 pages

Answer (score 1):

.NET runs on the server, **not the client**.

You can use your browser debugger and monitor the NETWORK panel to see where the delay is, regardless of the technology used.

Comment: The thing is that I need to monitor from a client's location (we are hosting the web app), as we suspect the problem might be due to their internet connection. Considering only end users not in IT are there, asking them to open up the browser debugger to try and measure the performance might not be the best solution we have...

That's why I was wondering if there is some javascript we can insert that will "know" when the method end so that I can have the end time as well...

Answer (score 1):

If your save function is calling something server side.

Just do this:

```
//start of function
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;

.
.
.
.

//end of function, right before return
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
```

The ts will give you totalseconds, totalminutes, etc...

Answer (score 1):

**For server side methods** :

you need to enable tracing to get to know what process and which method is getting time on server side.
http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/435/aspnet-tracing/

**For client side**

fiddler or ySlow can help you in this regards.

Advance:
Ant profiler can help you to find bottle neck in your code